# angular 2 pass variable through component chain

Tags: angular, binding

I have a nested chain of components that is at least 4 deep, parent -> child -> grand-child -> great-grand-child.  I know how to pass a variable step by step through the chain but I would like to be able to pass it directly from parent to great-grand-child.  Otherwise I have to write a fair bit of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to circumvent having to pass the data down the components would be to share the data in a service, which can be injected into all relevant components. Just be sure to provide the service at the appropriate level to take advantage of [hierarchical dependency injectors](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html).

Comment: This looks like the right way to do what our application is trying to do.  Thanks.